# How can I know the red, blue and red component value of a pixel in a color image using openCV?

Tags: opencv

The pixel value of a colored image represents the total of the Red , green , blue component 
effect . I want to extract the exact value for each component using opencv, Please suggest !

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the [OpenCV FAQ Wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq#How_to_access_image_pixels):

```
Suppose, we have 8-bit 3-channel image I (IplImage* img):

I(x,y)blue ~ ((uchar*)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*y))[x*3]
I(x,y)green ~ ((uchar*)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*y))[x*3+1]
I(x,y)red ~ ((uchar*)(img->imageData + img->widthStep*y))[x*3+2]
```

You might also want to get a copy of O'Reilly's [Learning OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) and read it if you're planning to do any serious work with OpenCV - it will save a lot of time on very basic questions such as the above.

Comment: A more updated book would be [OpenCV 2 cookbook](http://www.amazon.com/OpenCV-Computer-Application-Programming-Cookbook/dp/1849513244).

Comment: @karlphilip: even this book seems to get a lot of negative reviews saying that it's outdated - I guess it depends a lot on whether you want to use the old C API or the newer and more changeable C++ API.

Comment: Since RGB components are stored in pixel memory as 8bit channel for each. I'm using following code to get values of individual component RGB. Please suggest                                                              IplImage*image = cvLoadImage("image.jpg")                       for (i = 0; i < ih; i ++) {
    for (j = 0; j < iw; j ++) {
         int pixel = Pixelmap[i][j];
         int r = 0xff & (pixel >> 16);// Obtain the red Component
         int g = 0xff & (pixel >> 8); // Obtain the green Component
         int b = 0xff & (pixel);  // Obtain the blue component;

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to learn [opencv c++ api](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/). Pixels are represented by vector of uchar.
If this is a color image then we have 3 uchar by pixel.
Opencv defines `typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b;` then:

```
//load image
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("myimage.png",1); // 1 means color image
/* Here the cv::Mat can be seen as cv::Mat_<Vec3b>
 * Matrix of uchar with 3 channels for BGR (warning this is not RGB) 
 */
// access to pixel value
cv::Vec3b mypix = img.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
uchar bluevalue = mypix.x;
```

Comment: Since RGB components are stored in pixel memory as 8bit channel for eachfor (i = 0; i < ih; i ++) {
    for (j = 0; j < iw; j ++) {
         pixel = fillPixelmap[i][j];
         r = 0xff & (pixel >> 16);// Obtain the red Component
         g = 0xff & (pixel >> 8); // Obtain the green Component
         b = 0xff & (pixel);      // Obtain the blue Component

Comment: I've write the code as:int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("I.jpg");
        int nl= img -> height; // number of lines
        int nc= img -> width * img -> nChannels;  // total number of element per line
        int step= img->widthStep; // effective width
        int channel = img -> nChannels;

        //load image
        cv::Mat_<Vec3b> img1 = cv::imread("myimage.png",1); // 1 means color image
              // access to pixel value
        cv::Vec3b mypix = img1.at<Vec3b>(5,5);
        uchar bluevalue = mypix.x;
        return 0;
}
then get error as

Comment: error as- load_im.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:     error: ‘Vec3b’ was not declared in this scope
 note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:248:23: note:   ‘cv::Vec3b’
load_im.cpp:15:16: error: template argument 1 is invalid
load_im.cpp:15:23: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
load_im.cpp:15:51: error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘int’ in initialization
load_im.cpp:18:25: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘img1’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
load_im.cpp:19:26: error: ‘cv::Vec3b’ has no member named ‘x’

Comment: Please give a demo code, to extract R,G,B values individually from a pixel of color image in openCV

Answer (score 1):

This code will print the red and blue value of pixel 300, 300:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
b,g,r = (img1[300, 300])
print (r)
print (b)
```